# [RESOLVE]ODBC Driver Manager] Data Source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: vb.net, odbc, advanced-installer

I created a vb project and made an installer of it, it works fine with my pc and it also works on some of the users who used the system on their machine, but then there's this particular user of received this error, please help T.T

I tried...

1. checking my connection string on my vb project just to make sure, but it's fine.
2. check if my system deployed is 32 bit and the MySQL ODBC connector, both are 32 bit.
3. tried checking if the MySQL ODBC driver is properly installed on the 32-bit ODBC data source, 
   I search this win + R (c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe) to make sure that I'm in a 32-bit data source since both 64 bit and 32-bit data source has the same name on my laptop.

[image: 64-bit Data Source]

[image: 32-bit Data Source]

also, i notice that the drivers installed on 32 bit data source doesn't have version,company and such (refer to image 2), while on the 64 bit data source it does have version, company and such (refer to image 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that the network of that particular user has block the access to the installed drivers, it got resolve when they connect to a different network.